# Cannot test Facebook OAuth in development because 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs' not allowing localhost

Tags: facebook, localhost, facebook-oauth

In Facebook Login Settings (in `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs`), when I attempt to add `http://localhost:8000/survey`, I get the following message,...,

> `http://localhost redirects are automatically allowed while in development mode only and do not need to be added here.`

So, when I attempt to use `http://localhost:8000/survey` in my `redirect_uri=` parameter on my `https://www.facebook.com/v7.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=...` URL for FB login, I get this error message on the FB login  page:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Okay,... so I'm not allowed to whitelist `http://localhost:8000/survey` by adding it to `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` -- where it says that `http://localhost redirects are automatically allowed` -- but then when I actually use a localhost URL, it is not whitelisted.

How is it possible test my app's FB login in a localhost/development environment?  (I'm familiar with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), but is there another way besides that?)

Comment: I have no problem calling the login dialog, with an app in development mode, and that _exact_ redirect URI you mentioned. Do you have app domain and website URL also set accordingly?

Comment: When I use my production URI (https) in 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs', the FB dialog box comes up just fine, but when I assign localhost to the redirect_uri parameter, I still get the non-whitelisted error from FB.  Even if I don't put my production URI into the "App Domains" box, it still works fine as long as I have it in 'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs'.  Confused....

Answer (score 1):

The first part you quoted mentions the app being set in Development Mode:

> http://localhost redirects are automatically allowed while in **development mode** only and do not need to be added here.

You can toggle this from the top right corner of your App Dashboard on Facebook's site. More detailed instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/managing-development-cycle/#step1

Another alternative that you have is using your `hosts` file to point a domain name to your localhost, if you can't set your app in development mode.